# after click create button Line Manager Name become blank How to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I work on asp.net MVC  . I face issue Line Manager Name display based on auto complete selection Line Manager Id.

and after select Line Manager Id from auto complete List Line Manager Name display based on selection Line Manager Id

after click submit button create action fire and page load but Line Manager Name not display
so

How to solve this issue please

full code details

```
@model HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.ResignationRequester


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Resignation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "mainform", style = "padding-top: 50px" }))
{




    <div class="form-horizontal">
       

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LineManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtLineManagerId" } })
                </div>
            </div>
          
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.Label("Employee Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" id="LineManagerName" class="form-control" />
                   
                </div>
            </div>
          

        </div>
        <div id="searchContainer">

        </div>

        <div id="searchContainerDirector" style="margin-left:900px;">

        </div>

        



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>
}


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"
        language="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtLineManagerId").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
                console.log("search text" + searchText)
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
                    data: { searchText: searchText },
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            console.log("data is" + item.EmployeeID);
                       
                            return { label: item.EmployeeID, value: item.EmployeeID, employeeName: item.EmployeeName };

                        }))

                    }
                });
            },
            position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom" },
            appendTo: '#searchContainer',
            select: function (event, ui) {

                $("#LineManagerName").val(ui.item.employeeName);
            }
       
        });

       



</script>


public class ResignationController : Controller
    {
 public ActionResult GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText(string searchText)
        {
            JDEUtility jde = new JDEUtility();
         
            List<object> employeeListCriteria = new List<object>();
            employeeListCriteria = jde.GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText(searchText);
            return Json(employeeListCriteria, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
     }
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ResignationRequester resignationRequester)
        {
        return View(resignationRequester);
        }
```

image show issue by details
[image: image show issue by details]

**Updated Post**

I don't have any property for Line Manager Name because I store Line Manager Id instead ON database .

my question How to use Hidden field to pass data after submit so it will not clear

Comment: thanks for support can you please provide me more support details please

Comment: can you provide me solving issue step by step please because answer not clear for me so if possible can you provide me solving issue step by step please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your autocomplete's select function, set the value of the hidden field LineManager instead of setting the value of the Line Manager Name input field. This way, when the form is submitted, the LineManager value will be properly sent to the server.

  `select: function (event, ui) { $("#txtLineManagerId").val(ui.item.label); $("#LineManager").val(ui.item.label);     }`
- the form submission is not sending the data to the server properly. In your
  Create action, you are returning the same resignationRequester object, which
  would not persist the form data.

  `[HttpPost]

  ```
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ResignationRequester resignationRequester)
    {
        database, etc.

        return RedirectToAction("SuccessAction");
    }`
  ```
- Ensure that the hidden field for LineManager is properly defined in your
  model and is being included in the form. You might need to add this to your
  form:

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LineManager)`

- see if this code above helps you